# Make post preview empty if excerpt is blank with Timber

Tags: timber

I've tackled this issue before in vanilla Wordpress however I can't seem to find a way to keep the post.preview object blank if the excerpt field is empty. Despite searching around no one else seems to find this an issue!

Anyway, I've come up with a work around based on my previous methods to set a variable in my logic files for the twig template to use which is simple enough and someone else may find useful. Just intrigued to see if I'm missing something that would be possible from within Timber.

Here's the solutions I used and it was placed in page.php

```
$excerpt = '';
if ( ! has_excerpt() ) {
    $excerpt = '';
} else { 
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
}
$context['post_excerpt'] = $excerpt;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`post_excerpt` is already a property of `Timber\Post`. If post is in your context, you probably don't need to add another var just for this.

To embrace doing things a more 'Timber-esque` way, access the property off the object, rather than setting another var in the context.

```
{# page.twig *}

{% if post.page_excerpt %}
    {{ post.preview }}
{% endif %}
```

This also has less reliance on globals (like `has_excerpt()`  or `get_excerpt()` ) so it becomes easier to reuse this code in other templates or files.

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 7 this should also work as expected and is a much cleaner solution:

```php
$context['post_excerpt'] = get_the_excerpt() ?? '';
```

The `??` operator is called the 'Null Coalescing Operator'. You can find more about it in the [official PHP docs](https://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce).

An alternative solution is to use the timber "preview"-method on the post class directly in your twig template:

```
{{ post.preview }}
```

You can find more info about this in the official [Timber](https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-postpreview/) docs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion man, however as I said in my question the Timber preview class doesn't have a method to check if the excerpt is manually added.